React with JavaScript Button onClick
I need a better understanding of how JavaScript functions work with React.
I have a "Button" with an "onClick" event that I want to "reset" an "input" text field.  I just can't get it to work.
Solution:  When the "Reset" button is clicked, the "SearchText" input text field is cleared of any characters.
Code

import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { faMagnifyingGlass, faPeopleGroup, faBuildingUser, faArrowsRotate } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import utilStyles from '../styles/utils.module.css';

const SearchText = ({ cards, setSearchResults, setEnteredText }) => {

  const enteredText = ' ';

  const onChangex = useCallback((event) => {
    var enteredText = event.target.value;
    setEnteredText(enteredText);
  }, []);

  const onFormSubmit = (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();

  }
  
  const onChange = (event) => {

    if (!event.target.value) return setSearchResults(cards);

    const fields = ['NAME', 'CAMPUS', 'DEPARTMENT', 'JOBTITLE'];
    const query = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const filterData = (cards, fields, query) => {
      return cards.filter(record => fields.some(field => record[field]?.toLowerCase().includes(query)));
    };

    setSearchResults(filterData(cards, fields, query));

  }

  const onReset = (event) => {

    console.log("Clicked Reset");
    const container = document.getElementById("SearchText");
    container.reset();

  }

  const resetSearchInput = (event) => {

    console.log("Clicked");
    var enteredText = event.target.value;
    setEnteredText(enteredText);

  }


  return (
      
    <>
      
      <form id='EmployeeSearchText' onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
        <div className="container-fluid p-3">
          <div id='Row1' className={`row ${utilStyles.divPadding}`}>
            <div id='Row1Column1' className="col">
              <div id='SearchText-container' className={utilStyles.searchBar}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} className={utilStyles.icon} />
                <input id='SearchText' type="text" onChange={onChange} className={`form-control ${utilStyles.inputField} ${utilStyles.inputPadding}`} name="SearchText" placeholder="Search Last Name; First Name; Campus; Deparment....." />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='text-center'>
            <div id='Row2' className={`row ${utilStyles.divPadding}`}>
              <div id='Row2Column1' className="col">
                <div id='Employees-container'>
                  <button id='EmployeeListing' className={utilStyles.btnYellow}>Employees&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPeopleGroup} /></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id='Row2Column2' className="col">
                <div id='DepartmentListing-container'>
                  <button id='DepartmentListing' className={utilStyles.btnYellow} type="button">Department Listing&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBuildingUser} /></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id='Row2Column3' className="col">
                <div id='SearchTextReset-container'>
                  <button id='SearchTextReset' onClick={onReset} className={utilStyles.btnGrey} type="button">Reset&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowsRotate} /></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>     
      
    </>
  
  )
}

export default SearchText;



What does happen when you click the reset button? Are there any errors in your dev console? What have you done to debug it?

First, I don't see where setSearchResults is defined. Is it defined in a different component? What might be happening is that since you have a change event set on the input, when you clear it that might trigger a change, which would run the code that is defined in setSearchResults.

mykaf,  I get "container.reset is not a function".

bprdev, it's defined in a different component.  The application does work but I can't get the "reset" button to clear the input field.  It appears that someone has provided a solution.  I figured I was doing something wrong but didn't know what that might be.

You can use controlled components on your text!
1 - Create a State for your input
2 - Add the State you created as a value on your input
3 - Use the OnChange to change the State to the value you typed
4 - Just use the OnClick on the button to reset the State to an empty string
OBS: I changed the OnClick to just reset the state, if you want your full function just add changeTextInput("") to it
const [textInput,changeTextInput] = useState("") // Creating a state

  const onChange = (event) => {

    if (!event.target.value) return setSearchResults(cards);
    
    changeTextInput(event.taget.value) // Changing the state when typing on the input
   
    const fields = ['NAME', 'CAMPUS', 'DEPARTMENT', 'JOBTITLE'];
    const query = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const filterData = (cards, fields, query) => {
      return cards.filter(record => fields.some(field => record[field]?.toLowerCase().includes(query)));
    };

    setSearchResults(filterData(cards, fields, query));

  }


  return (
      
    <>
      
      <form id='EmployeeSearchText' onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
        <div className="container-fluid p-3">
          <div id='Row1' className={`row ${utilStyles.divPadding}`}>
            <div id='Row1Column1' className="col">
              <div id='SearchText-container' className={utilStyles.searchBar}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} className={utilStyles.icon} />
                <input value={textInput} id='SearchText' type="text" onChange={onChange} className={`form-control ${utilStyles.inputField} ${utilStyles.inputPadding}`} name="SearchText" placeholder="Search Last Name; First Name; Campus; Deparment....." /> // Adding the value and the OnChange function
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='text-center'>
            <div id='Row2' className={`row ${utilStyles.divPadding}`}>
              <div id='Row2Column1' className="col">
                <div id='Employees-container'>
                  <button id='EmployeeListing' className={utilStyles.btnYellow}>Employees&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPeopleGroup} /></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id='Row2Column2' className="col">
                <div id='DepartmentListing-container'>
                  <button id='DepartmentListing' className={utilStyles.btnYellow} type="button">Department Listing&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBuildingUser} /></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id='Row2Column3' className="col">
                <div id='SearchTextReset-container'>
                  <button id='SearchTextReset' onClick={changeTextInput("")} className={utilStyles.btnGrey} type="button">Reset&nbsp;&nbsp;<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowsRotate} /></button> //Clearing the state when clicked
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>     
      
    </>
  
  )
}

export default SearchText;


Kobra,  I see.  Thank you.  I figured I was doing something wrong but just didn't know what was wrong.

Do I need "return" within "onChange" and "filterData"?  Or is it good practice to include it?  While learning React, I thought I read that "return" was implied.

In your case, your function onChange does not have to return anything, because it just performs an action without needing to give back any result.
For filterData function, you need the return as this function is supposed to give back filtered results based on the input parameters.
:D

If you consider this as the answer, mark it as the answer please

If you want to clear filter values you may achieve this following method.

Create a state for that filter.
const [filterValue, setFilterValue]= useState('')
set state when your onchange function trigger.

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setFilterValue(event.target.value)
    if (!event.target.value) return setSearchResults(cards);

    const fields = ['NAME', 'CAMPUS', 'DEPARTMENT', 'JOBTITLE'];
    const query = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const filterData = (cards, fields, query) => {
      return cards.filter(record => fields.some(field => record[field]?.toLowerCase().includes(query)));
    };

    setSearchResults(filterData(cards, fields, query));

  }


update input value according to this:

                <input id='SearchText' type="text" value={filterValue}  onChange={onChange} className={`form-control ${'utilStyles.inputField'} ${'utilStyles.inputPadding'}`} name="SearchText" placeholder="Search Last Name; First Name; Campus; Deparment....." />


Clear state on reset button click.

 const onReset = () => {
    setFilterValue('')
  };

